# Realation between continuity and invertiblity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a compact group of linear operators on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $|x|=\sup_{T\in G}||Tx||$. Then every member of $G$ w.r.t $|·|$ is isometry.

To this end, we can write 
$$|Sx|=\sup_{ T\in G }|TSx|= \sup_{ TS\in G }|TSx|=|x| $$.

Why? Is it true: since $G$ is group, $TS$ is invertible, continuous (why?) and in $G$???

Comment: Any linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to itself is continuous.  A composition of linear transformations is continuous.

Comment: That is right. Thus,   since $G$ is group, what does it imply?

Comment: As $T$ runs through all the elements of $G$ exactly once, again $TS$ is going to run through all the elements of $G$ exactly once.  You might like to write this as $$|Sx| = \sup\limits_{T \in G} |TSx| = \sup\limits_{V \in G} |Vx| = |x|$$

Comment: Yes. But by your comment, it implies that if $G$ is semigroup, then $TS\in G$. Well, what is necessarity of group?

Comment: You need the function $f: G \rightarrow G$ given by $f(T) = TS$ to be a bijection from $G$ to $G$, which is not true for general semigroups.

Comment: Thanks so much... Now, if $ f$ be bijective, what's happen? I

Comment: Then that tells you the middle equality is true.

Comment: Can you explain about the Theorem that you use to this end??

Comment: Just think about it.  You are taking the supremum over the same set of numbers..